# Identification of huge larva in South Tyrol

Tags: species-identification, entomology

On a sunny autumn day (19.09.2021) i saw a huge green larva crossing the street facing a wineyard. The picture was taken near Bozen, South Tyrol (22 °C that day). It is at least 14 cm long and 2 cm thick. It is entirely green, besides black and yellow stripes at each "segment" and with black spots at the lower part of the body. Additionally there is an red/black anal spine.

I would have guessed it is some kind of *Acherontia atropos*, but i am not entirely sure.
[image]

Comment: Is that a green horn catepillar? Don't know anything about them or if that is even what they are called but when I saw that photo that name came into my memory somehow. Google seems to correct that term to hornworm catepillar. 4 inches. Similar pattern too.

Comment: Sure looks like tomato hornworm, _Manduca quinquemaculata_ or similar tobacco hornworm _M. sexta_, but Manduca is an American genus.  _Agrius convolvuli_ is European and similar larva, but seems to have a stripe connecting the slashes of the segments.

Comment: After some additional research, i would agreelso conclude its one of the larval stages of *Agrius convolvuli* , which looks pretty similar. So i guess mgkrebbs was right. A friend of mine, working as an agricultural entomologist said, that especially the black stripes of the larva can change during the developement.